# Profile error when launching google-chrome

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide 'Your profile could not be opened correctly'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14903/hide-your-profile-could-not-be-opened-correctly)

Whenever I launch google-chrome, a window is displayed which contains this message:

> Your profile could not be opened
>   correctly.
>
> Some features may be unavailable. 
>   Please check that the profile exists
>   and you have permission to read and
>   write its contents.

What is the source of this problem?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other article is about hiding the error message on a public Internet café machine; this one is about correcting the error. Please unmark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This worked for me. Give it a try, this procedure includes a backup of your google-chrome profile folder, so that you can revert it if this seems not to work for you.

Pasted here for your convenience.

> 1. If the browser is open, close it
>      down.
> 2. Open a terminal and run: `mv
>      ~/.config/google-chrome
>      ~/.config/google-chrome-old`
> 3. Launch google-chrome, you will be
>      asked to choose your search engine,
>      your choice.
> 4. Close coogle-chrome (yes, click the
>      close button)
> 5. After closing the browser you will
>      have a new user profile at
>      `~/.config/google-chrome`
> 6. Then let's copy your profile into
>      the new place by running the next in
>      the terminal.     `cp -r 
>      ~/.config/google-chrome-old/Default
>      ~/.config/google-chrome/`

I hope this help you.

Good luck!

Comment: can i remove after all this `google-chrome-old` folder?

Comment: Yeah, sure you can. It was created just as a backup in case that you  wish to restore the profile as mentioned in step 6. You can -indeed- to simply remove the original files without backing up, after which Google Chrome will create a new (empty) one.

Comment: This is yet working in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Comment: hm. i am pretty sure it works in 13.04, why do you think it will not work ?

Comment: Oh well, I wasn't asking. Just informing that it works in 12.04 but thank you anyway.

Comment: great solutions,work for me

Comment: I got this same error, and found it was because there was a google-chrome process that was stuck in the background. I just did "killall -KILL chrome" in the terminal and that fixed it.

Comment: Removing the google-chrome directory did not work for me — Chrome came up with the same error pop-up when restarted, and did not prompt for anything. I also found an old process and killed it, but that too made no difference at all: I still get the error message. This is Version 31.0.1650.63 Ubuntu 13.04 (31.0.1650.63-0ubuntu0.13.04.1~20131204.1) under Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Somehow the same process didn't work for of on 12.04 a couple of times until I rebooted the computer. I haven't tried this on 13.04 or newer and it seems to be a new kind of a bug on chrome. If you already tried rebooting please inform. Thank you!

Comment: @BenDavis worked for me, thanks. Make it an answer! For those who use chromium the command is `killall -KILL chromium-browser`

Comment: The killall command did it for me

Answer (score 9):

Probably it is a bad permission on the directory where the profile is stored. Your user should have rw permission and be the owner of it.

`~/.config/google-chrome`

is probably the directory so you may have to execute:

```
sudo chmod -R u+rw ~/.config/google-chrome
sudo chown -R your_user ~/.config/google-chrome
```

or simply remove the directory so Chrome will make a new one:

```
rm -r ~/.config/google-chrome
```