# Profile error when launching Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I launch Google Chrome, a window is displayed which contains this message:

> Your profile could not be opened correctly.
>
> Some features may be unavailable. Please check that the profile exists and you have >permission to read and write its contents.

At first I tried to remove `~/.configure/google-chrome` folder, and restarted Google Chrome. It created a new `google-chrome` folder, but it doesn't solve the problem. The same window is displayed again.

How do I solve the problem?

#### The Original Atricle from chinese douban community

> > Google在linux环境下对Chrome的使用做了限制，笔者猜测可能是基于安全的考虑，否则遇到配合XSS的挂马以及诸如此类的问题的时候，就会以root权限执行命令，这是相当危险的。但是Chrome的确是一款不错的浏览器，这样放弃实在舍不得。
> >
> > 于是：
> >     首先需要安装十六进制编辑器
> >
> > apt-get install hexedit
> >
> > 然后使用编辑器编辑Chrome
> >
> > hexedit /opt/google/chrome/chrome
> >
> > 注意：路径如果不同的话请自行使用dpkg -c安装包来察看安装到哪里了。
> >     进入到编辑器后，光标在左侧，首先按TAB键切换到右侧的ASCII码模式，接着按Ctrl+S打开搜索功能，输入geteuid查找，然后将geteuid改为getppid，最后按Ctrl+X保存退出。
> >     重新打开Chrome，正常运行。

### Translated in English

> > when you use google-chrome in Linux,you will find that there is some limitations,probably the limitations are based on safety considerations.
> >     Otherwise,if it is used in conjunction with xss and such kind of vulnerabilities,
> >     the hakcer is able to run command as root priviledge.This is very dangerous.
> >     But chrome is one of the greatest browsers.It's unwisdom to abandon chrome for this reason.
> >
> > so,we will do something to let chrome be free from this limitations.
> >
> > 1.Install the HexEdit,open a terminal and run: *sudo apt-get install hexedit*
> >
> > 2.and then edit Chrome wiht Hexedit: *sudo hexedit /opt/google/chrome/chrome*
> >     tips:Be sure you have the write privilege to chrome.
> >     if you don't have this privileges,run:*sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/google/chrome/chrome*
> >
> > Notice:if you have't install chrome in example directory,please run dpkg -c to find you r directory.
> >
> > - Enter the HexEdit,the cursor is on the left.
> > - Press the Tab let the cursor go to right which was Ascii model.
> > - Press Ctrl+S to open the search engine
> > - search  "geteuid"
> > - Replace "geteuid"  with "getppid"
> > - Press Ctrl+X ,save and exit.
> > - lanuch your chrome,it work properly.

### That'all

Comment: "But i found a way to solve the problem from douban community which located in china" Can you be more specific?

Comment: Of course,i traslate the article into English just now.And append the article to my question.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue of chrome. Try the following:

1. Quit Google Chrome.
2. Open a shell.
3. Change directory (cd) to ~/.config/google-chrome/Default
4. Delete the file named “Web Data”:  rm -rf Web\ Data;
5. Start Google Chrome and the error should be gone.

Alternatively, you can try the following first:

1) Click on the tool icon on the top right corner of your chrome browser 
2) On the drop down menu, click the signed in as .
3) Under users section, click the delete this user button and takes him off away.
4) Restart Google chrome and add the user and Chrome will be in a good shape..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new patched launcher for Google Chrome.

Just run Chrome from the new icon named "Google Chrome Patched" without any modification of the original files.

After installing the package google-chrome-stable, just run the following script as root to creat the new launcher:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-patched <<PATCHEND
#!/bin/bash

#
# This is a google-chrome patched launch script to fix the common profile connection error.
#
# By Luc Bruninx 2014-09-15 on Ubuntu 13.04
#

if [[ -d "\$HOME/.config/google-chrome.bak" ]]; then
  rm -fr "\$HOME/.config/google-chrome.bak"
fi

if [[ -d "\$HOME/.config/google-chrome" ]]; then
  mv "\$HOME/.config/google-chrome" "\$HOME/.config/google-chrome.bak"
  cp -r "\$HOME/.config/google-chrome.bak" "\$HOME/.config/google-chrome"
fi

\$(dirname \$0)/google-chrome

PATCHEND

chmod a=r+w+x /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-patched

cat /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop | sed "s/\/usr\/bin\/google-chrome-stable/\/opt\/google\/chrome\/google-chrome-patched/g" | sed > /usr/share/applications/google-chrome-patched.desktop "s/Google\ Chrome/Google\ Chrome\ Patched/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's a matter of multiple instances.

Try typing the following in a terminal:

`pkill chrome`

Then re-launch chrome.